# Capybara can't find a file to attach in an RSpec/Rails test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Capybara/RSpec to write a feature test in a Rails 5 app to check the uploading of images on my site.  I am getting this error:

```
  1) Photos user adds a photo
     Failure/Error: attach_file("photo[image]", '/app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg')


 Capybara::FileNotFound:
   cannot attach file, /app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg does not exist
```

My test is
require 'rails_helper'
require 'web_helpers'

```
RSpec.feature "Photos", type: :feature do
  scenario "user adds a photo", :type => :feature do
    add_photo
    page.should have_content("Instagram Logo")
    expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='instagram-logo.jpg']")
  end
end
```

Web helper:

```
def add_photo
  sign_up
  visit "/photos"
  click_button "New Photo"
  fill_in "Title", :with => "Instagram Logo"
  attach_file("photo[image]", Rails.root + '/app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg')
end
```

The view:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :photo_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :image %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, id: :photo_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

The HTML compiled from the view:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/photos" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="igZ4MndDfIQdZOmdiPxKu14bTIkAQTeKG+hwq0E6swKuskkkiCFwEVkarMgS26lc83z1eB/QyuQtnfFLRyuLWQ==" />

  <div class="field">
    <label for="photo_title">Title</label>
    <input id="photo_title" type="text" name="photo[title]" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="photo_image">Image</label>
    <input id="photo_title" type="file" name="photo[image]" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Photo" data-disable-with="Create Photo" />
  </div>
</form>
```

The file is definitely in that filepath.  I have tried it without the `Rails.root`, and also originally had it in the public folder where I tried `Rails.root + /public/instagram-logo.jp` and simply `/public/instagram-logo.jpg` and finally `instagram-logo.jp`.  Not sure if the issue is the filepath or perhaps a bit further back along the line.  Have also tried `attach_file("image"...` in the web_helper.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try  `attach_file("photo[image]", '/assets/instagram-logo.jpg')`

Comment: Same error, @pavan.  What was your logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an abolute path like `Rails.root + '/app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg'`, `Rails.root` will be ignored. Try `Rails.root + 'app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg'` and see what happens.

Also check if the File really exists with:

```
File.exist?(Rails.root + 'app/assets/images/instagram-logo.jpg')
```

(Since this is the error thrown by CapyBara https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3a2c5d21e756460d388995aa9698c4bc8c6ba49d/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L238)

FYI: This is a behaviour of `Pathname`:

```
pry(main)> Pathname.new("/this/is/my/root") + "/plus/absolute"
=> #<Pathname:/plus/absolute>
pry(main)> Pathname.new("/this/is/my/root") + "plus/relative"
=> #<Pathname:/this/is/my/root/plus/relative>
```